# EF Core query full join between many-to-many relation

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm working with EF core and I have a many-to-many relation between STUDENTS and SUBJECTS, like this:

```
public class StudentDetail
    {
        [Key]
        [JsonPropertyName("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(50)")]
        [JsonPropertyName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("StudentSubjects")]
        public virtual IEnumerable<StudentSubject> StudentSubjects {get; set;}
    }

 public class SubjectDetail
    {

        [Key]
        [JsonPropertyName("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(20)")]
        [JsonPropertyName("SubjectName")]
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("Teacher")]
        public virtual TeacherDetail Teacher { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("StudentSubjects")]
        public IEnumerable<StudentSubject> StudentSubjects { get; set; }
    }

public class StudentSubject
    {

        [JsonPropertyName("StudentId")]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("Student")]
        public StudentDetail Student { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("SubjectId")]
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("Subject")]
        public SubjectDetail Subject { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(3)")]
        [JsonPropertyName("Grade")]
        public string Grade { get; set; }
    }
```

I create my Databse using migrations, so after I did the migration, the database was created like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I need a query that bring me all the Subjects with their teacher and grade of an specific Student. I was tryng doing it like this:

```
var subjects = await _context.StudentSubject
                               .Include(s => s.Subject)
                               .Where(sid => sid.StudentId == student.Id)
                               .Select(st => st.Subject)
                               .Include(t => t.Teacher)
                               .ToListAsync();
```

But I'm getting an ERROR saying that I'm tryng to use `Include();` on a non Queryable Entity. Anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to use `public virtual ICollection<T>` instead of `public IEnumerable<T>`. There may be more to change, but that might help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Include will only work if you are having a link between two table and that is defined by keyword Virtual in C# classes. Please use public virtual ICollection instead of public IEnumerable and follow the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectquery-1.include?view=netframework-4.8) for more details. If you still wants to continue with same class then try using join in Linq queries.